# Google Vision API - tatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED

Tags: gcloud

I am new to the Google Vision API and I would like to conduct a label detection of approx. 10 images and I would like to run the vision quickstart.py file. However when I do this with only 3 images then it is successful. With more than 3 images I am getting the error message below. I know that I would need to change something at my setup, but I do not know what I should change.

Here is my error message:

```
google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry method 
that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that 
terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Insufficient tokens for 
quota 'DefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 
'vision.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number: XXX'.)>)
```

Does anybody know what I need to do?

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it with these steps:

1. Make sure you have the Google Cloud SDK properly installed: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries
2. Setup a Service Account in the Google Cloud backend: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount
3. Create a Service Account Key and download it as a JSON file to a local folder. You need to keep the key private.
4. Export the filepath to the key-file as an environment variable: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file path/to/your/keyfile/here`
5. Log out/in of the console.
6. Make sure, the environment variable is properly set with `printenv`
7. Try your py-script again...

Good luck...

Edit: In addition to the mentioned steps 1.-3. you can just do `vision_client = vision.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/your/keyfile.json')` in your script. No need for the env variable then.

Comment: See also this: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html